# Why does my Python program run in an IDE(pycharm) but not when i try it from command line?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, pycharm

I'm new to Tensorflow. The code in question in given below:

```
import tensorflow as tf

g = tf.Graph()

with g.as_default():

x = tf.constant(8, name="x_const")
y = tf.constant(5, name="y_const")
my_sum = tf.add(x, y, name="x_y_sum")

with tf.Session() as sess:
print(my_sum.eval())
```

The above code runs without any errors in PyCharm giving the correct result. But when i try the same code from the command line, i get the some errors which i've provided a screenshot of.
[screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XG2kN.png)

I'm unable to understand the reason for the error. The main line in the error states:

```
"Cannot use the default session to evaluate tensor: the tensor's graph is 
different from the session's graph.Pass an explicit session to 
'eval(session=sess)'"
```

But even when i give an explicit session, it shows almost the same error. I also don't understand why it is running without any errors in PyCharm IDE.

My system:

- Windows 7 Ultimate(64-bit)
- 4GB RAM
- Intel Pentium 2020M processor
- Intel HD Graphics
- Python 3.6.5(64-bit)
- Tensorflow version 1.5.0

Answer (score 1):

Pass  graph to the session.

```
with tf.Session(graph=g) as sess:
    print(my_sum.eval())
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks. But i still don't understand why the code worked in PyCharm without passing default graph to the session.